# How to get real sql from NHibernate with Log4Net

Tags: sql, nhibernate, log4net

I decided to learn how to use an ORM to avoid learning some SQL (mistake -- only approach would be to go no-SQL).

I have been able to get the Nhibernate "SQL" using Log4Net, using the instructions that are duplicated in quite a few blogs. I get "SQL" like this:

```
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: 2011-11-11 15:03:14,348 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Loader.Loader [(null)] - SELECT this_.RegionID as RegionID9_0_, this_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_0_ FROM Region this_
```

Now correct me if I am wrong but that is not SQL, and I can't understand why all of these blogs talk like it is.

The strange thing is that earlier when I was messing around with log4net, I am sure that I was able to get ordinary SQL logged to a logfile. When I basically did getall() of an entity (read a whole table), all of the individual queries were listed there with the id in the query -one for each row(entity). I definitely didn't imagine this. Can anyone tell me how this is done with log4net? Here is my config right now:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="DebugSQL" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <param name="File" value="log.txt"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
          <conversionpattern value="%d %p %m%n">
          </conversionpattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.Loader.Loader" additivity="false">
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="DebugSQL" />
</logger>
```

Edit: I now know that it was sql, and I couldn't reproduce the emitted sql that I had seen earlier because lazyloading was on before:

```
NHibernate.SQL: SELECT region_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_ FROM Region region_ WHERE region_.RegionID=@p0;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate.SQL: SELECT region_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_ FROM Region region_ WHERE region_.RegionID=@p0;@p0 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate.SQL: SELECT region_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_ FROM Region region_ WHERE region_.RegionID=@p0;@p0 = 3 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate.SQL: SELECT region_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_ FROM Region region_ WHERE region_.RegionID=@p0;@p0 = 4 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Comment: "all of the individual queries were listed there with the id in the query -one for each row(entity)" -- this is a prime example of where understanding SQL would help you tremendously.  Search for "nhibernate N+1"

Comment: Well I was not imagining seeing x queries for x rows. The reason was that it does this when lazyloading is on. Btw when I said I should have skipped SQL altogether, I meant I should have skipped to an object database or graph database. I am not against learning SQL eventually, but using an ORM just feels wrong and like a huge hack. The programing language domain deals in objects and it seems clear to me that the database should too.

Comment: You said pretty clearly in your other comment that you were expecting to see X queries in X rows.  When using alternative database you will encounter just as many issues (if not more) than with a relational one.  But if you are uncomfortable with the solutions offered in the most mature option, and resort to calling them a "huge hack" I doubt you will be any more comfortable with an alternative. At the end of the day, everything we do is "a huge hack", but some of them actually turn out pretty well.

Comment: Bit of a miscommunication about the first line in my question. I should have said that I wish I had skipped relational databases. I am sure that NHibernate served a purpose but I think it is probably becoming anachrostic along with relational databases. I gave nhibernate a very good try and got it working, with 1 session per request, l2 caching and logging working..eventually. But it was a bit of a nightmare. I see no point in all this when there are object databases....

Comment: ...The original problem arose from not being able to reproduce the sql that was emitted, and the difference was explained by lazyloading. With lazyloading on a field I get this: (see edit on my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see after the dash in the log is indeed SQL. It is syntactically and semantically correct, but it just looks plain ugly. This is commonplace when SQL is not written manually: code generators use names such as `RegionID9_0_` for disambiguation, making the output look unusual to a human reader.

Comment: OK, so it is just plain ordinary SQL. THanks. I Managed to do the query in Management Studio: SELECT this_.RegionID as RegionID9_0_, this_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_0_ FROM Northwind.dbo.Region this_

Answer (score 2):

change the conversionPattern on the 4th line from:

```
%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline
```

to

```
%message%newline
```

and you will log only the SQL (it's the value of %message)

the following line, from your log, is SQL:

```
SELECT this_.RegionID as RegionID9_0_, this_.RegionDescription as RegionDe2_9_0_ FROM Region this_
```

Comment: Yep, the problem was basically that I expected that there would be x queries to get x rows. So i thought that the SQL was HQL or something.